# How to get the text from a checkbutton in python ? (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

My code looks something like this

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter

top = Tkinter.Tk()
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
CheckVar2 = IntVar()

C1 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Music", variable = CheckVar1, onvalue = 1,  offvalue = 0 )
C2 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Video", variable = CheckVar2,onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0 )
```

I have created two checkbuttons with values and some text.
If I want to print the values of the checkbuttons i use this code:

```
print CheckVar1.get()
print CheckVar2.get()
```

But I also want to print the text of the Checkbutton. I tried to the following:

```
print C1.get("text")
print C2.get("text)
```

Which does not work at all.Is there some trick for this? Or do I have to create some workaround like this: (Which seems quite strange)

```
 CheckVar1 = IntVar()
 CheckVar2 = IntVar()
 Name1 =  StringVar(value="Music")
 Name2 =  StringVar(value="Video")

 C1 = Checkbutton(top, text = Name1, variable = CheckVar1, onvalue = 1,  offvalue = 0 )
 C2 = Checkbutton(top, text = Name2, variable = CheckVar2,onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0 )

print Name1
print Name2
```

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: @Kevin thank you. I forgot to mention that i added the `grid` function, which returned me `None` all the time. Now I split my checkbuttons like this `C1 = ... ` and `C1.grid(....)` and now the `cget()` function works! Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to get the text from the UI? That's a code smell. UIs are not for storing values but for communicating with the user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
print C1.get("text")
print C2.get("text")
```

To get the value of a widget's attribute, try using `cget`.

```
print C1.cget("text")
print C2.cget("text")
```

Comment: I tried this as well and get the following error: print self.C1.cget("text")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cget'

Comment: Are you doing `C1 = CheckButton(...).pack()` when creating the widget? That makes it impossible to access its attributes. See [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute get](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/953482) for more information.